# The security to the murdered president’s “what am I?” riddle party [Part TREE(3)]

Tags: password

François Hollande, famous Cordon Bleu chef that he (like all French presidents) is, has invited a select few guests to his party, where he will be showing off the secret cheese-making process that doubles as a plan of attack against Britain. Your task as a UK spy (who happens to also be an Argentinian agent) is to steal this recipe for disaster. Entrance to the château wherein lies the party, however, is overseen by two guards. One guard always lies, and the other always tells the truth.

You arrive early and hide in some bushes. Guests begin approaching the door, and it becomes clear that there is some kind of password involved.

- One guest arrives by himself. “1”, says a guard. “6”, replies the guest. He is permitted entrance.
- Two more guests show up. “3” is prompted; “2” is the response, and it is apparently correct.
- A group of seven is next to request entry, and the guards see fit to ask them each in turn.

  - “2!” “7.”
  - “11!” “6.”
  - “20!” “4.”
  - “4!” “2.”
  - “6!” “3.”

  The group had been doing fine until that last person, whose throat is promptly slit, along with those of what look to be his wife and son. “You were just off by one!”, says one of the guards, who looks like the sort of person who would tell the truth – but then again, it’s hard to tell with them. You’re not in Argentina anymore.

You think you’ve figured out the pattern, though, and are about to take your turn when another guest arrives, late. The challenge is given – “26” – but before the guest can give an answer, a loud gunshot is heard. Someone shouts out the window that the president is dead! It’s a coup d’état! You must get to the plans before the assassin, but one guard is still performing his duty. You are given the number five as a challenge; what is your response?

Comment: What a story........ looks like Homeland in medieval times..;)

Comment: Are the Argentina references and the president's murder hints or just extra red-herring details?

Comment: @randal'thor: References to other puzzles on the site. The Argentina ones don’t matter, no.

Comment: To clarify "until that last person" - does this mean that responding "3" to the guard's "6" is incorrect? Or is the interaction of this last person omitted from the list?

Comment: @Leo: Yes, it means that responding “3” to “6” is incorrect.

Comment: My answer would be to tell the guard to attend to the source of the gunshot! But on a more serious note, is the fact that one guard lies and one tells the truth another one of those references? I am assuming that the number sequence is "truth"?

Comment: @breadvelvet: Yes, and it’s just a joke. No bearing on the puzzle. (At least, not until part TREE(3) + 1.)

Comment: what was the answer???

Comment: @mani_nz: I’m going to wait a little longer!

Comment: Do we know which guard is asking, and which guard is confirming the response.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code: Which one tells the truth is a joke and not relevant. (An action can’t be a lie.)

Comment: Ok so is there an answer for this ?

Comment: When the guards say "11!", is that the number 11 in an exclamatory fashion, or is that "11 factorial"?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: The former!

Comment: If the guard had said "2" to the first guest, would the response still have been "7" (as it was for the fourth guest)?  I'm wondering if the order they arrive or the number in their group has anything to do with their answers.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: Yes, it would have been the same.

Comment: Would anyone ever have gotten in with another answer? i.e. are there ever two correct responses to a prompt (for the same size group).

Comment: @alexmc: No, there are never two correct responses to a prompt. The size of the group doesn’t matter; the wording and setting is more important (but I’ve apparently made this too obscure, sorry).

Comment: What's the answer

Comment: Can we get a hint for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> 6

The rule is

> If the number that the guard tells you is n, respond with the number of letters in the nth word of [The French National Anthem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Marseillaise) (in French, of course).

Here is the first stanza:

> **French lyrics**
>  Allons enfants de la Patrie,
>  Le jour de gloire est arrivé !
>  Contre nous de la tyrannie,
>  L'étendard
>   sanglant est levé, (bis)
>  Entendez-vous dans les campagnes
>   Mugir ces féroces soldats ?
>  Ils viennent jusque dans nos bras
>   Égorger nos fils, nos compagnes !

All of the words match, and the incorrect answer (off by one) fits as well!

[image]

Comment: The response to 3 was 2, not 6. So no typo.

Comment: This is it! Well done.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 20 times, so glad it finally got answered! Great job JLee

Comment: @alexmc Thanks! I had never seen this puzzle til yesterday. I don't know how I missed it. I just got lucky. The French National Anthem (which I didn't even know existed til I Googled it) was my first idea. Surprising I got it, because I'm usually better at creating puzzles, rather than solving them.

Answer (score -3):

I'm guessing the answer is 0. All the answers are to have an implicit relation with number 5.

1 - 6 = 5 |
3 + 2 = 5|
2 - 7 = 5|
11 - 6 = 5|
20 / 4 = 5

But the last two was not so. As the last person is found wrong but the one before that is not means that guest was questioned by the guard who speaks lies and the last guest was questioned by the guard who speaks truth.

```
   “You were just off by one!”, says one of the guards who looks like the sort of person who would tell the truth – but then again, it’s hard to tell with them.
```

This means that what the guard told was a lie.

Comment: And the 4 and 2?

Comment: Also, the respond to answering '3' to '6!' was that its only one off.  6 and 2 do not make 5 in any sense and neither do 6 and 4 (unless you take the average but that is a stretch).

Comment: @quy : That might have been asked by the guard who lies.

Comment: @Leo:  '3' to '6!' was that its only one off, said by a guard who could be lying. Read it again. It says he could tell the truth but not sure

Comment: @mani_nz the OP already said in a previous comment that the lie/truth aspect has no bearing on the puzzle and that it is just a reference. In the event that it DID have a bearing on the puzzle we could just pick and choose which Q&A examples we want to use to fit an operation <- this would not make sense as it would make the solution too loose.

Comment: One of the guards could have lied about them being off by one, but whether they admit the guest or not isn’t subject to that. 4 → 2 is a correct answer. Good try, though!

Comment: @minitech: Awww.. Was I atleast close ?? :)

Comment: @mani_nz: I’m afraid not.

Comment: It seems there is no relation between numbers. Only way, I can think of to solve it, is put the numbers said by guard in increasing order and analyse the responses.